# How to spawn mobs upon a players death

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I've done a number of test and looked up a ton of videos and all I can find is making random saying happen in chat when a player dies. I'm trying to make a GTA style police system so I want 3 vindicators to spawn with the custom name Cop where a player dies. However, I can't find anything that locates where any player dies.

Comment: There's two parts to this. 1: How to trigger a command when a player dies. 2: The right command to spawn a Vindicator with a custom name. Which of those parts do you need help with? (Edit: If the issue is just that you can't locate where the player dies, then please post an attempt that spawns them in an arbitrary location, like `(0,128,0)`, so that we have something to work with.)

Comment: I have figured out how to trigger something when a player dies but not where a player dies which is what I need to spawn them in the correct location and I know how to spawn vindicators with custom names I just don't know how to spawn them in the WHERE sinario